# Error in installing pip in python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, pip

Tried to install pip in python 2.7.6 in windows 7 by downloading get-pip.py and running by python get-pip.py .but getting timeout error

```
Collecting pip
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
    tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034F5DB0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
    org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
    tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034F5E50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
    org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
      Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
    tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034F5F30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
    org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
      Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
    tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034F5FD0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
    org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
      Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
    tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034F5970>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
    org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
```

Comment: There is a problem with your connection to the Internet and you are unable to reach pypi.python.org

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, it checks the network for the update version. You can disable it with `--disable-pip-version-check`, then it should not use the retry mechanism.

use:

```
PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1
```

It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Find [pyvisa](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) download it.
2. Paste it in your python interpreter folder and place it in scripts folder.
3. Open command prompt from scripts folder by pressing and holding on shift key and right clicking.
4. once you open command prompt type `pip install pyp` and hit tab it will give the path.
5. Finally enter to execute.